# Empty space below table in JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I´m designing a report with `JasperReports`. That uses a table component to display the data. Table component use `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` as dataSource.  The thing is that when I see the preview it displays several tables on the same page and it creates several pages too, even though my dataSource only returns 4 records, I have done a lot of search and found nothing.

My report design (in `iReport`): 
[image: Report design in iReport]

The resulting report, the first page:

[image: The first page of the resulting report]

and the second one:

[image: The second page of the resulting report]

Comment: What do those tables contain? Or are they just empty? Are the tables spread out evenly across the pages or do you have empty pages? It would also be helpful if you could provide some of the relevant parts of the report and maybe a screenshot of the preview

Comment: There are links of a report: http://i.imgur.com/ffxLk.png 
http://i.imgur.com/Sa4IE.png

Below the table it generates top and bottom border of a table as many as there are rows.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/bjWHP.jpg - this is a screenshot of iReport

Comment: @bashe15 You should post your `jrxml` file

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to put the table component into the title band or summary band so you only get one table. You could also (or instead) change the main report query to return a single row or to display All Rows No Detail when the main query has no records.

Answer (score 0):

There could be different reasons causing this behavior:

- Too much space above / below the table in the detail band: make sure the detail band (and every other band) is exactly as high as it needs to be to avoid excessive space
- Somewhere in the report is an unwanted element (which is repeated for every record)
- There is something wrong with the query or the dataset and empty or too many records are created